# Show view Page with dynamic html content from model property

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my .Net MVC 3 application I need to make this functionality:
When user click on the button, it should navagate him into some page but with  html content that I have in model property. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, inside the view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@Html.Raw(Model.SomePropertyThatContainsHtml)
```

But that's completely ridiculous, you'd rather have your controller action directly return `ContentResult`:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    MyViewModel model = ...
    return Content(model.SomePropertyThatContainsHtml, "text/html");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.
Use  on this new view

```
@Model YourModel
@{
     Layout = null;
}
@Html.Raw(Model.Propery)
```

Comment: thanks, so use advise me to create new view and some dynamic content will be on it? In this view it is only code that I need?